# Sharepoint Custom Row Formatting of Selected Row

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I've been looking everywhere and I cannot find the JSON schema to format a selected item on a list.  I see the conditional formatting codes as well as hiding a selection code but not formatting the specific selected item.

The following is the formatting I am looking to accomplish:
(selected row) - border
(unselected rows) - opaque/lighten up to keep focus on selected item.